# What is the most accurate way to cap frame rate in C++?

Tags: c++

I need the frame rate of my code loop to be exactly 20 milliseconds to the micro second. The way I was doing this before works somewhat, but it’s not working in a different class function. I don’t have my code to paste now sadly. However, I would like to know what the most accurate to the microsecond way to make the time be 20 milliseconds every time.

Comment: Frame rate of what? Which OS? What have you tried? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Re. `"I need the frame rate of my code loop to be exactly 20 milliseconds to the micro second"`: really?  What happens if you're, say, 10 microseconds out?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It’s for a VEX VRC robot. I’ve tried using the chrono library to check if the current time is == to whatever 20 ms is in microseconds. It worked for driver control, where you are driving, but it gives off completely random values during auton, when the robot drives. 

The goal is to manually cap the refresh rate to make my robot move in auton as precisely close to the driver control as possible. 

Auton - robot drives itself

Comment: For an example code of what I basically tried:            While (1)       if (current time >= 20 ms) {
   Break;
}

Comment: _to whatever 20 ms is in microseconds_ FYI: 20 ms is 20000 microseconds.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My specific problem is this: the current code I pasted does not give me accurate times. It currently goes under the threshold of what I need. I need a .1 millisecond difference between two different runs of code. One is driving, which is fine, the other is auton (Robot running) and that’s fine.the problem is when I try to make them both run at the same speed, I cannot, due to this code not working as well as it should be. It has about 3 second flexibility. Resources are not a problem for the onboard computer.

Comment: You are going to need a real-time operating system or maybe write your own.  Modify the timing ISR so that every 20ms, it will call your function (often called a hook).  You'll need to profile your code so that you know it will not use up all the time in the ISR.

Comment: Well I definitely can’t write my own, I’m pretty new to c++ and I’m a little preoccupied with finding documentation for neural networking, but I can maybe install another OS. Maybe. Idk.